# Logging a string of big size in java

Tags: java, logging, io

I'm using logback and I need to log all data queried by clients, to a log file. All the data queried by clients is needed to be logged to the same file. The logging process simply looks like below:

```
private static final OUTPUTFILELOGGER = Logger.getLogger(...);
String outputString = null;
try {
    Map<String, Object> outputMap = doService();    // queries data requested by clients.
    .... // do something after business logic..
    outputLog = outputMap.toString();    // critical!!
} catch (Throwable e) { 
   handling exception
} finally {
   OUTPUTFILELOGGER.info(outputString);
}
```

It usually works fine, but sometimes it arises OutOfMemoryError with the call of toString to the outputMap variable when the requested data is too big to make a string.

So I want to make it work in a way of streaming without any problem to performance. And I don't know how to make it effectively and gracefully.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the map so that you're only working with a small part at a time:

```
LOGGER.info("Map contains:")
map.forEach( (key, value) -> LOGGER.info("{}: {}", key, value));
```

(Assumes Java 8 and SLF4J)

However if the map is big enough for the code you've given to generate OOMs, you should probably consider whether it's appropriate to log it in such detail -- or whether your service ought to be capping the response size.